# Wrong element shows up in Firebase querySnapshot

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I´m doing an app in Swift and I got an array with numbers and want to fetch some data in Firebase.

The problem is that the `getDocuments` scramble my iteration.

When I do a test with to print outs, the first prints out 0,1,2,3 but the second, the one inside `getDocuments`, shows 0,2,1,3

```
let test = ["20180905212533","20180905220014","20180905212533","20180905220014"]
for recepieID in 0 ... test.count-1{
   print (recepieID) //Shows right recepieID = 0,1,2,3
   db.collection("Recipes")
     .whereField("created", isEqualTo: test[recepieID])
     .getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
        print (recepieID)// Do not show right recepieID = 0,2,1,3
      }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This operation is asynchronous , you can't guarantee that the server will respond serially , Either use a serial queue

```
let q = DispatchQueue(label: "CustomQueue")
let test = ["20180905212533","20180905220014","20180905212533","20180905220014"]
for recepieID in 0 ... test.count-1{
   q.async {
   print (recepieID) //Shows right recepieID = 0,1,2,3

   db.collection("Recipes")
     .whereField("created", isEqualTo: test[recepieID])
     .getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
        print (recepieID)// Do not show right recepieID = 0,2,1,3
      }
}}
```

**OR**

```
load(0)
```

//

```
func load(_ recepieID:Int) {

   db.collection("Recipes")
 .whereField("created", isEqualTo: test[recepieID])
 .getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
    print (recepieID)// Do not show right recepieID = 0,2,1,3
    if recepieID < test.count {
       load(recepieID+1)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know that I could force Firebase into serial queue.

Comment: I tried you solution and I got the same result. After been reading abut the problem, it seems that I still got async callbacks even though i should be sync. But I have to read more about this problem. I can't validate your solution, right now, but I will come back to it later on, after my research.

Answer (score 1):

why you use -1 remove this may be it's working find then :-

```
for recepieID in 0 ... test.count{
   print (recepieID)
}
```